# Android Search View with recycler view and checkbox in recycler items

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-checkbox

I have an activity which has, search view and recycler view. The recycler items contains checkbox, Assume there are 5 items(A,B,C,D,E) in recycler view . In normal, when I click checkbox on A/B/C/D/E,it works fine, when I search C on search view, the filter is done and it shows result of C alone, when I check C and close the search, the check is reassigned to A as it is in position 0 and C remains unchecked. I need to check based on user Id. How to achieve this?

Comment: share the code which you have written

Comment: Add some of the relative code, it might help.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you need to validate data in proper manner.You just store the id of checkbox item when user is selecting to it.and after that you validate the checkbox data in onBindView() method of recycle adapter. I hope its help you.

Answer (score 0):

For questions without code references, one can expect answers in the same manner, so first, try putting some code as well in the question.
 In a nutshell, you need to save the selected state of the checkbox in your data model so that when the list is reloaded, you can get that selected state of checkbox and assign it to `isChecked` property, this can be done in `onBindViewHolder`. Hope this helps.